# Can I run .net 3.5/4.0 website under a root folder of .net 2.0 website?

Tags: .net

Say, abc.com, have all the files in the root folder is one saperate application. And, data is a subfolder but a different application. Our concern is if the root folder is 2.0, can the application (which is a different application, not included in the root application) in a subfolder  be 3.5/4.0?

Answer (score 2):

The framework is tied to the Application pool. So the subfolder would have to be running under a different pool

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can run code that is compiled for .NET 3.5 under the same Application Pool that is running a .NET 2.0 application. The reason is that .NET 3.5 is actually built on top of .NET 2.0. .NET 3.5 is effectively extensions for .NET 2.0. Thus, they could share the same Application Pool. However, .NET 4.0 is a totally different framework. You cannot run .NET 2.0/3.5 in the same Application Pool as .NET 4.0.